# How to set Encoder for Row, LabeledPointData in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

How to set Encoders for LabeledPointData which is combination of Double, Vectors of Double. How to set Encoders for creating DataFrame?

```java
public static Dataset<LabeledPoint> convertRDDStringToLabeledPoint(Dataset<String> data,String delimiter) {
    Dataset<LabeledPoint> labeledPointData = data.map(
            (data1)->{
                String splitter[] = data1.split(delimiter);
                double[] arr = new double[splitter.length - 1];
                IntStream.range(0,arr.length).forEach(i->arr[i]=Double.parseDouble(splitter[i+1]));
                return new LabeledPoint(Double.parseDouble(splitter[0]), Vectors.dense(arr));
            },Encoders.???);
    return labeledPointData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`LabeledPoint` is a case class in Scala so I think it's `Encoders.product[LabeledPoint]`.

(I don't know how to write it in Java)